# Network manager flickering between device not managed, and no network devices available

Tags: networking, parrot-os

Used `sudo apt-get upgrade`

After reloading the machine, when I hover over the network icon in the top right it flickers between device not managed, and no network devices available.

I changed `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` to flip managed to true.

Running `ip link` will sometimes display wlan0 and will sometimes not, but when it does display wlan0 the number before it increases incrementally.

I can't copy the output due to having no connection on the machine, but after qdisc it has `noop state down`.

For `ifconfig` i get the output: `wlan0: error fetching interface information: Device not found`, and sometimes it does not find the device at all.

A similar output for `iwconfig` sometimes it will give information about wlan0 and sometimes it will state `No such device`

`tail syslog` gives `iwlwifi Firmware not running - cannot dump error`

`ip link set wlan0 up` returns either cannot find device or `RTNETLINK answers: Input/output error`

Answer (score 0):

So first, looking into the dump error lead to this forum:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=247575

From here it lead to this bug forum: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/63117

This says to downgrade the version of iwlwifi

Unfortunately, I am not able to downgrade and have it work, maybe someone else could explain that, but another workaround is to reboot, and at the grub menu go onto advanced and pick the previous kernel.

https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/10/how-to-keep-package-from-updating-in.html

https://www.tecmint.com/remove-old-kernel-in-debian-and-ubuntu/

Now type `sudo apt-mark hold firmware-iwlwifi`

`sudo apt-get upgrade` will now say there is no files to update

`uname -sr` to get the current kernel (the one where the wifi works)

`dpkg -l | grep linux-image | awk '{print$2}'`

`sudo apt remove --purge linux-image`

`sudo update-grub2`

`sudo reboot`

Now when you boot you should boot into the previous saved kernel

`sudo apt-mark showhold` -to make sure iwlwifi is still held

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt upgrade`

Now when you reboot you should have the updates without the new iwlwifi which has the bug

If I am wrong please correct me, this came from my own personal issue with the upgrade and this is how I fixed it for me, so if there is a much easier way please let those that come across this know